# change circle.yml file location

Tags: yaml, circleci

I am trying CircleCI and have some issues regarding `circle.yml` location. I have one repository and it is including some projects related to each others.

```
repo
|
|---- project-web
|
|---- project-assets
|
|---- project-android
```

I would like to include `circle.yml` inside each sub project. However `CircleCi` clearly states a `circle.yml` must be inside root directory of project. Is it possible to include `circle.yml` inside a sub-directory.

Comment: How did you fixed it? Please add that as an answer so that others will get benefited.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Kim from CircleCI.

Sorry, but you can't put circle.yml under non-root directory. I suppose you want to have a setting in each project, but I think you can still do that with a single circle.yml. If you want to discuss more about this, please come to our support. We can give you better support there!

Cheers,

Kim

Comment: Thanks I have contacted with you. I will provide necessary details here as a workaround.

Comment: Can you add your solution here so it benefits others as well? Thanks!